# Use 2 DHT22 AND PASS THE DATA TO SD?

Tags: sensors, sd-card

I have the code to pass the data from dht22 to sd but for only one and i want to pass the data from 1 dht22 with one file and the data from other sensor to other file and logging in to sd. Anyone can help me?

```
#include
#include
#include "DHT.h"
#define DHTPIN 8
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
File data_file;

int CS_pin = 10;
long sec=00;
long mint=00;
long hr=00;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(CS_pin, OUTPUT);
dht.begin(); //This command will start to receive the values from dht22
// SD Card Initialization
if (SD.begin())
{
Serial.println("SD card is initialized and it is ready to use");
} else
{
Serial.println("SD card is not initialized");
return;
}
}

void loop() {
data_file = SD.open("data.txt", FILE_WRITE);
if (data_file) {
getData();
}
// if the file didn't open, print an error:
else {
Serial.println("error opening data.txt");
}
delay(1000);
}

void getData(){
for(long sec = 00; sec < 60; sec=sec+2){
float temp = dht.readTemperature(); //Reading the temperature as Celsius and storing in temp
data_file.print(hr);
data_file.print(":");
data_file.print(mint);
data_file.print(":");
data_file.print(sec);
data_file.print(", ");
data_file.println(temp);
Serial.print(hr);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.print(mint);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.print(sec);
Serial.print(", ");
Serial.println(temp);
if(sec>=58){
mint= mint + 1;
}
if (mint>59){
hr = hr + 1;
mint = 0;
}
data_file.flush(); //saving the file
delay(2000);
}
data_file.close(); //closing the file
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It isn’t clear what you’re asking. You want to collect data from 2 sensors? What 2 files are you referring to? You have 2 source files? How are they structured? Why do you need 2 source files? Why not write a function that collects data from 2 sensors?

Comment: To me it was pretty clear, what the question was. And OP also acknowledged that in his comment below my answer...

Comment: @oh.dae.su you're a better man (or woman) than I. I took it to mean 2 different sketch files but outputting the data to 2 different files on the SD card makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Duncan C my comment was not intended as a direct answer to you, but in general in response to the question being put on-hold as unclear... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to setup the second DHT sensor and a second file. Please replace the `X` by the number of the pin your second sensor is connected to after `#define DHTPIN2`

```
#define DHTPIN 8
#define DHTPIN2 X
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
DHT dht2(DHTPIN2, DHTTYPE);
File data_file, data_file2;
```

In `setup()` you need to also start the second dht sensor:

```
dht.begin(); //This command will start to receive the values from dht22
dht2.begin(); //This command will start to receive the values from dht22
```

In `loop()` you have to open the second data file in addition to the first one:

```
data_file = SD.open("data.txt", FILE_WRITE);
if (data_file) {
getData();
}
// if the file didn't open, print an error:
else {
Serial.println("error opening data.txt");
}
data_file2 = SD.open("data2.txt", FILE_WRITE);
if (data_file2) {
getData2();
}
// if the file didn't open, print an error:
else {
Serial.println("error opening data2.txt");
}
```

Although not the most efficient/elegant solution, this requires you to duplicate your `void getData()` function as `void getData2()` to work for the second sensor/file, by replacing `dht` by `dht2` and `data_file` with `data_file2`.
This would do the logging on the two sensors in sequence.
If you want the logging in parallel you need to add the measurement and writing of the second sensor/file into the `void getData()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now finally i can do it ;)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help. Btw. please read the stack exchange tour page https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour to learn, how things work out on this site, e.g. how to deal with answers to your questions.

Comment: I don't know why but the program now say File does not name a type.

Comment: @jawad bouhali please either ask a separate question including the code and the exact error message or edit your question and append this information to it.